# systemd unit stops when required unit is stopped, but then does not start again when required unit starts

Tags: systemd

I've got a unit that I'll just call `eth-service` that requires another unit that I'll call `eth-server`.  In the unit file of `eth-service` I have

```
Requires=eth-server.service
After=eth-server.service
```

Now, when I run `systemctl stop eth-server`, then `eth-service` stops as well, as it should.  However, later when I run `systemctl start eth-server`, unfortunately `eth-service` remains inactive, so I have to remember to re-start it.

I'm trying to make my unit file setup as idiot-proof as possible (especially against myself) - is it possible to set up my unit files so that when the server starts up, the service does too?  If I were to put into my `eth-server` unit file:

```
Requires=eth-service.service
Before=eth-service.service
```

so that they mutually require each other, that would cause the service to start up when the server does, but it also means that when I run `systemctl stop eth-service` then `eth-server` stops too, since it now requires the service, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 3):

Let me see if I understood the use-case:

1. Starting `eth-service` should start both `eth-server` and `eth-service`.
2. Starting `eth-server` should start both `eth-server` and `eth-service`.
3. Stopping `eth-server` should stop both `eth-server` and `eth-service`.
4. Stopping `eth-service` should ONLY stop `eth-service` and leave `eth-server` running.

You can achieve it by adding `WantedBy=eth-server.service` to the [Install] section of the `eth-service.service` file, or `Wants=eth-service.service` to the [Unit] section of the `eth-server.service`.

According to the [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Wants=) `Wants` is a weaker version of the `Requires`, and it seems like if `Wanted` unit is stopped, the unit that requested it is not affected. But there might be an undesirable side-effect in this setup where `eth-server` will start no matter if `eth-service` fails to start or not.

### Unit file examples

Following sample unit files can be saved in the home directory (`~/.config/systemd/user`) and used with `systemctl --user` parameter.

Services described by those unit files don't do anything, but the `RemainAfterExit=yes` forces systemd to assume that the service is still running, even though the `/bin/true` command does not hang around after it is executed.

#### etc-service.service

```
[Unit]
Description=eth Service
Requires=eth-server.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=eth-server.service
```

#### eth-server.service

```
[Unit]
Description=eth Server

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

Enable the `eth-service.service` module with `systemctl --user enable eth-service.service`.

Following is the output of tests with starting/stopping services:

#### Initial State

```
$> systemctl --user status eth-service
● eth-service.service - eth Service
   Loaded: loaded (/home/ektich/.config/systemd/user/eth-service.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

$> systemctl --user status eth-server
● eth-server.service - eth Server
  Loaded: loaded (/home/ektich/.config/systemd/user/eth-server.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead)
```

System is returned into initial state before commands in following two sections are executed.

#### systemctl --user start eth-service.service

Both `server` and `service` are started (ignore the `exited` lines: both server and service are executions of /bin/true, which exits once it is finished, but the unit files are written so that systemd will think services are running until they are stopped)

```
$> systemctl --user start eth-service.service 
$> systemctl --user status eth-service
● eth-service.service - eth Service
   Loaded: loaded (/home/ektich/.config/systemd/user/eth-service.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-05-29 20:50:01 IST; 28s ago
  Process: 1578 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1578 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

$> systemctl --user status eth-server
● eth-server.service - eth Server
   Loaded: loaded (/home/ektich/.config/systemd/user/eth-server.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-05-29 20:50:01 IST; 2min 59s ago
 Process: 1579 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1579 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

#### systemctl --user start eth-server.service

Both services are started:

```
$> systemctl --user start eth-server.service
$> systemctl --user status eth-service
● eth-service.service - eth Service
  Loaded: loaded (/home/ektich/.config/systemd/user/eth-service.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-05-29 20:56:03 IST; 7s ago
 Process: 1681 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1681 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

$> systemctl --user status eth-server
● eth-server.service - eth Server
   Loaded: loaded (/home/ektich/.config/systemd/user/eth-server.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-05-29 20:56:03 IST; 12s ago
  Process: 1680 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1680 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Commands in following two sections are executed where both services are running:

#### systemctl --user stop eth-server.service

```
$> systemctl --user status eth-service
● eth-service.service - eth Service
   Loaded: loaded (/home/ektich/.config/systemd/user/eth-service.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

$> systemctl --user status eth-server
● eth-server.service - eth Server
   Loaded: loaded (/home/ektich/.config/systemd/user/eth-server.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

You can see both services were stopped

#### systemctl --user stop eth-service

```
$> systemctl --user stop eth-service
$> systemctl --user status eth-service
● eth-service.service - eth Service
  Loaded: loaded (/home/ektich/.config/systemd/user/eth-service.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2018-05-29 21:05:25 IST; 34s ago
 Process: 1800 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1800 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 29 21:04:23 ektich systemd[479]: Starting eth Service...
May 29 21:04:23 ektich systemd[479]: Started eth Service.
May 29 21:05:25 ektich systemd[479]: Stopped eth Service.

$> systemctl --user status eth-server
● eth-server.service - eth Server
   Loaded: loaded (/home/ektich/.config/systemd/user/eth-server.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-05-29 21:04:23 IST; 2min 58s ago
  Process: 1799 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1799 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 29 21:04:23 ektich systemd[479]: Starting eth Server...
May 29 21:04:23 ektich systemd[479]: Started eth Server.
```

You can see that `eth-service` has been stopped (`Active: inactive (dead)`) but the `eth-server` is still "running" (`Active: active`)

The status command for `etc-service` produced more output compared to other cases, I'm assuming because the "transaction" hasn't finished yet (`etc-server` is still running). The extra lines from `journalctl` show that as far as systemd is concerned one of the services has been stopped, and the other is still running.

PS according to the [systemd homepage](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) it is spelled **systemd**, not **SystemD** (just being pedantic)

Answer (score 1):

The `systemctl start xxx` generally **doesn't revert** the effects of a preceding `systemctl stop xxx`.

Admins need to learn that in the course of their career one way or another. Good news is that it's really easy to learn, because the feedback is immediate.

One way to revert manual stops and manual starts is to:

```
systemctl default
```

But this way is hardly fool-proof, as it **stops services which are not *enabled***, such as services running under various clusters (in particular pacemaker does not even see it as a problem/failure and does not react to it - it treats it as an intended admin action).

What can you do as an author of a service to make it fool-proof? How other programmers handle it is they avoid *any* dependencies and prefer to pack multiple processes into a single umbrella service. In the default RHEL7 install, there are no service dependencies *at all*. For example postfix:

```
$ systemctl status postfix
[...] Tasks: 3
   CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           ├─1288 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
           ├─1290 qmgr -l -t unix -u
           └─7340 pickup -l -t unix -u

$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service
[Unit]
Description=Postfix Mail Transport Agent
After=syslog.target network.target
Conflicts=sendmail.service exim.service

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/network
ExecStartPre=-/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb
ExecStartPre=-/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/postfix reload
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Just a note – `.snapshot` units (and `systemctl snapshot`) were removed in systemd v228, released 2015-11-18.